# How to send just one parameter in put method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, put

I'm trying to update just a parameter of the object, by expecting this:

```java
@PutMapping("{id}/nome")
public ResponseEntity<?> putDisciplinaNome(@PathVariable int id, @RequestBody String nome)
```

and sending the json like this:

```
{
    "nome": "Matematica"
}
```

but the result is this:

```
"nome": "{\"nome\":\"Matematica\"}"
```

what am i doing wrong here? there's another way of sending this parameter?

Comment: Try using a [PATCH](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789) to update a field of an object.

Comment: Also show how u're sending the request.

Comment: Show how do you create request, especially the request body.

Comment: try adding `consumes = "text/plain"` as parameter to @RequestMapping, like this:
`@RequestMapping(value="/myendpoint", consumes = {"text/plain"})` This will force it to treat the object as plain text instead of as a JSON object

Comment: also, since its only one field you want to update, you might want to consider using `@RequestParam` or even `@PathVariable` for this.

Comment: @Maurice so i can keep sending as json?

Comment: @chriptus12 i tried using patch, but nothing changed

Comment: @AnaPaulaLima no send as plain text, or better yet as a request parameter. The name of the parameter should be nome. Replace `@RequestBody` with `@RequestParam`

Comment: @Maurice it worked :D thank u

Answer (score 1):

Create a class for request body contains one field and use class as request body.

```
class DisDto {
      String nome;
}
```

```
@PutMapping("{id}/nome")
public ResponseEntity<?> putDisciplinaNome(@PathVariable int id, @RequestBody DisDto disDto) {
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying wrapping you're body in an input type like this.

```java
public class InputNome {
    String nome;
    
    //...
}

@PutMapping("{id}/nome")
public ResponseEntity<?> putDisciplinaNome(@PathVariable int id, @RequestBody InputNome body) {
    System.out.println(body.nome);
}
```

This way when you're sending the request the body (assuming JSON) will be something like this.

```
{
    "nome": "...."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to keep sending as json, so i cast the string to JSONObject like this:

```java
public ResponseEntity<?> putDisciplinaNome(@PathVariable int id, @RequestBody String json) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json2 = null;
         try {
             json2 = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json);
         } catch (ParseException e) {
             return new ResponseEntity<>("Json could not be formatted.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
         }
        Disciplina d = disciplinaService.getDisciplinabyID(id);
        if (d == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(d, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } else {
              d.setNome(json2.get("nome").toString());
              return new ResponseEntity<>(d, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
}
```

and now is working :D

Comment: You don't need to parse json, spring automatically can do that for you,  see my  solution :)